# how to include a prototype in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am learning angular 2 and I have written a ts definition for a truncate method I want to use in one of my services.

truncate.ts

```
interface String {
    truncate(max: number, decorator: string): string;
}

String.prototype.truncate = function(max, decorator){
   decorator = decorator || '...';
   return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+decorator : this);
};
```

How do I import this into another typescript module or at least make it available to use globally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

using typescript 2.3.4 in an Ionic 3 Angular 4 app I create a file called stringExtensions.ts and put this in it

```
export { } // to make it a module

declare global { // to access the global type String
  interface String {
      truncate(max: number, decorator: string): string;
  }
}

// then the actual code
String.prototype.truncate = function(max, decorator){
   decorator = decorator || '...';
   return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+decorator : this);
};
```

Comment: using export {} & declare global {} was magic sauce for me compared to other examples... and then for the record, i did NOT have to do any other import in my usage scope per other examples. Thanks Peter!

Comment: is it posible to prototype boolean? to i can add a method like toggle() ?

Comment: You should probably ask that as another question but something like Boolean.prototype.toggle = function(){return this=!this}

Answer (score 12):

> How do I import this into another typescript module or at least make it available to use globally.

Move it to a file `stringExtenions.ts`:

```
interface String {
    truncate(max: number, decorator: string): string;
}


String.prototype.truncate = function(max, decorator){
   decorator = decorator || '...';
   return (this.length > max ? this.substring(0,max)+decorator : this);
};
```

And import the file like:

```
import "./stringExtensions"
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: this compiles but the truncate method doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4):

In my case TypeScript 2.3.4, use

```
declare global {
    interface Date {
        format(format: string): string;
    }
}
```

The TypeScript document [Augmenting global/module scope from modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules)